# Docker-compose and extended Dokerfile: External Providers not found

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow, airflow-2.x

I've deployed apache airflow using docker-compose using an extended image to include requirements. I can see in the airflow UI that the snowflake providers package was installed (apache-airflow-providers-snowflake), but for some reason, I'm getting a DAG import error:

```
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.snowflake'
```

I've logged into the docker webserver, used the airflow user, and successfully imported this package.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.3.0-python3.9


USER root
COPY requirements.txt .


RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y apt-utils

USER airflow
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

see below:

```
[philip@ip-10-5-51-10 airflow_2]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                                 NAMES
0516db2653a0   airflow_2_airflow-webserver         "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About an hour ago   Up 52 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp             airflow_2_airflow-webserver_1
36142cc09a6b   airflow_2_airflow-scheduler         "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About an hour ago   Up 52 minutes (healthy)   8080/tcp                                              airflow_2_airflow-scheduler_1
c090e86e9279   airflow_2_airflow-triggerer         "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About an hour ago   Up 52 minutes (healthy)   8080/tcp                                              airflow_2_airflow-triggerer_1
ade8996d759f   airflow_2_airflow-worker            "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About an hour ago   Up 52 minutes (healthy)   8080/tcp                                              airflow_2_airflow-worker_1
8915e4fb4ffe   airflow_2_flower                    "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About an hour ago   Up 52 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, :::5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp   airflow_2_flower_1
353f2fa5552f   postgres:13                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 52 minutes (healthy)   5432/tcp                                              airflow_2_postgres_1
1bafa42ece77   redis:latest                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 52 minutes (healthy)   6379/tcp                                              airflow_2_redis_1
408ad15538ce   denny/monitor-docker-slack:latest   "/monitor-docker-sla…"   12 months ago       Up 3 days                                                                       monitor-docker-slack
[philip@ip-10-5-51-10 airflow_2]$ docker exec -u 0 -it airflow_2_airflow-webserver_1 bash
root@0516db2653a0:/opt/airflow# su - airflow
airflow@0516db2653a0:~$ pip list
Package                                  Version
---------------------------------------- ------------
adal                                     1.2.7
alembic                                  1.7.7
amqp                                     5.1.1
anyio                                    3.5.0
apache-airflow                           2.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-amazon          3.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-celery          2.1.4
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes 4.0.1
apache-airflow-providers-docker          2.6.0
apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch   3.0.3
apache-airflow-providers-ftp             2.1.2
apache-airflow-providers-google          6.8.0
apache-airflow-providers-grpc            2.0.4
apache-airflow-providers-hashicorp       2.2.0
apache-airflow-providers-http            2.1.2
apache-airflow-providers-imap            2.2.3
apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure 3.8.0
apache-airflow-providers-mysql           2.2.3
apache-airflow-providers-odbc            2.0.4
apache-airflow-providers-postgres        4.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-redis           2.0.4
apache-airflow-providers-sendgrid        2.0.4
apache-airflow-providers-sftp            2.6.0
apache-airflow-providers-slack           4.2.3
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake       2.6.0
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite          2.1.3
apache-airflow-providers-ssh             2.4.3
apispec                                  3.3.2
argcomplete                              1.12.2
asn1crypto                               1.4.0
attrs                                    20.3.0
Authlib                                  1.0.1
azure-batch                              12.0.0
azure-common                             1.1.28
azure-core                               1.23.1
azure-cosmos                             4.2.0
azure-datalake-store                     0.0.52
azure-identity                           1.9.0
azure-keyvault-secrets                   4.4.0
azure-kusto-data                         0.0.45
azure-mgmt-containerinstance             1.5.0
azure-mgmt-core                          1.3.0
azure-mgmt-datafactory                   1.1.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg                3.0.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-store                0.5.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg                         3.0.2
azure-mgmt-resource                      21.0.0
azure-nspkg                              3.0.2
azure-storage-blob                       12.8.1
azure-storage-common                     2.1.0
azure-storage-file                       2.1.0
Babel                                    2.9.0
bcrypt                                   3.2.0
beautifulsoup4                           4.11.1
billiard                                 3.6.4.0
blinker                                  1.4
boto3                                    1.16.59
botocore                                 1.19.59
cached-property                          1.5.2
cachelib                                 0.6.0
cachetools                               4.2.2
catboost                                 0.25.1
cattrs                                   1.10.0
celery                                   5.2.6
certifi                                  2020.12.5
cffi                                     1.14.4
chardet                                  3.0.4
charset-normalizer                       2.0.12
click                                    8.1.2
click-didyoumean                         0.3.0
click-plugins                            1.1.1
click-repl                               0.2.0
clickclick                               20.10.2
cloudpickle                              2.0.0
colorama                                 0.4.4
colorlog                                 4.0.2
commonmark                               0.9.1
configparser                             3.5.3
connexion                                2.13.0
cron-descriptor                          1.2.24
croniter                                 0.3.37
cryptography                             3.3.1
cycler                                   0.11.0
dask                                     2022.2.0
db-dtypes                                1.0.0
decorator                                5.1.1
defusedxml                               0.6.0
Deprecated                               1.2.13
dill                                     0.3.3
distlib                                  0.3.4
distributed                              2022.2.0
dnspython                                2.1.0
docker                                   5.0.3
docutils                                 0.16
elasticsearch                            7.13.4
elasticsearch-dbapi                      0.2.9
elasticsearch-dsl                        7.4.0
email-validator                          1.1.2
eventlet                                 0.33.0
filelock                                 3.6.0
Flask                                    1.1.2
Flask-Admin                              1.5.4
Flask-AppBuilder                         3.4.5
Flask-Babel                              1.0.0
Flask-Caching                            1.10.1
Flask-JWT-Extended                       3.25.0
Flask-Login                              0.4.1
Flask-OpenID                             1.2.5
Flask-Session                            0.4.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy                         2.4.4
flask-swagger                            0.2.13
Flask-WTF                                0.14.3
flower                                   1.0.0
fonttools                                4.33.3
fsspec                                   2022.3.0
funcsigs                                 1.0.2
future                                   0.16.0
gevent                                   21.12.0
google-ads                               14.0.0
google-api-core                          2.7.2
google-api-python-client                 1.12.11
google-auth                              2.6.6
google-auth-httplib2                     0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib                     0.5.1
google-cloud-aiplatform                  1.12.1
google-cloud-appengine-logging           1.1.1
google-cloud-audit-log                   0.2.0
google-cloud-automl                      2.7.2
google-cloud-bigquery                    2.34.3
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer       3.6.1
google-cloud-bigquery-storage            2.13.1
google-cloud-bigtable                    1.7.1
google-cloud-build                       3.8.1
google-cloud-container                   1.0.2
google-cloud-core                        2.3.0
google-cloud-datacatalog                 3.7.1
google-cloud-dataplex                    0.2.1
google-cloud-dataproc                    4.0.2
google-cloud-dataproc-metastore          1.5.0
google-cloud-dlp                         1.0.1
google-cloud-kms                         2.11.1
google-cloud-language                    1.3.1
google-cloud-logging                     3.0.0
google-cloud-memcache                    1.3.1
google-cloud-monitoring                  2.9.1
google-cloud-orchestration-airflow       1.3.1
google-cloud-os-login                    2.6.1
google-cloud-pubsub                      2.12.0
google-cloud-redis                       2.8.0
google-cloud-resource-manager            1.4.1
google-cloud-secret-manager              1.0.1
google-cloud-spanner                     1.19.2
google-cloud-speech                      1.3.3
google-cloud-storage                     1.44.0
google-cloud-tasks                       2.8.1
google-cloud-texttospeech                1.0.2
google-cloud-translate                   1.7.1
google-cloud-videointelligence           1.16.2
google-cloud-vision                      1.0.1
google-cloud-workflows                   1.6.1
google-crc32c                            1.3.0
google-resumable-media                   2.3.2
googleapis-common-protos                 1.56.0
graphviz                                 0.16
greenlet                                 1.1.2
grpc-google-iam-v1                       0.12.4
grpcio                                   1.44.0
grpcio-gcp                               0.2.2
grpcio-status                            1.44.0
gunicorn                                 20.1.0
h11                                      0.12.0
HeapDict                                 1.0.1
httpcore                                 0.14.7
httplib2                                 0.19.1
httpx                                    0.22.0
humanize                                 4.0.0
hvac                                     0.11.2
idna                                     2.10
importlib-metadata                       3.10.1
importlib-resources                      5.7.1
inflection                               0.5.1
iso8601                                  0.1.13
isodate                                  0.6.0
itsdangerous                             1.1.0
Jinja2                                   2.10.3
jmespath                                 0.10.0
joblib                                   1.0.0
json-merge-patch                         0.2
jsonpath-ng                              1.5.3
jsonschema                               3.2.0
kiwisolver                               1.4.2
kombu                                    5.2.4
kubernetes                               23.3.0
lazy-object-proxy                        1.4.3
ldap3                                    2.9.1
locket                                   1.0.0
lockfile                                 0.12.2
looker-sdk                               22.4.0
lxml                                     4.8.0
Mako                                     1.1.4
Markdown                                 3.3.4
MarkupSafe                               1.1.1
marshmallow                              3.15.0
marshmallow-enum                         1.5.1
marshmallow-oneofschema                  3.0.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy                   0.26.1
matplotlib                               3.5.2
msal                                     1.17.0
msal-extensions                          0.3.1
msgpack                                  1.0.3
msrest                                   0.6.21
msrestazure                              0.6.4
mypy-boto3-rds                           1.22.0.post1
mypy-boto3-redshift-data                 1.22.0.post1
mysql-connector-python                   8.0.29
mysqlclient                              2.1.0
natsort                                  7.1.0
nox                                      2020.12.31
numpy                                    1.19.5
oauthlib                                 3.1.0
openapi-spec-validator                   0.2.9
oscrypto                                 1.2.1
packaging                                21.3
pandas                                   0.25.3
pandas-gbq                               0.17.4
paramiko                                 2.10.4
partd                                    1.2.0
pathspec                                 0.9.0
pendulum                                 2.1.2
Pillow                                   9.1.0
pip                                      22.0.4
platformdirs                             2.5.2
plotly                                   5.7.0
pluggy                                   1.0.0
ply                                      3.11
portalocker                              2.4.0
prison                                   0.2.1
prometheus-client                        0.14.1
prompt-toolkit                           3.0.29
proto-plus                               1.18.1
protobuf                                 3.20.1
psutil                                   5.8.0
psycopg2-binary                          2.9.3
py                                       1.11.0
pyarrow                                  6.0.1
pyasn1                                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                           0.2.8
pycparser                                2.20
pycryptodomex                            3.9.9
pydata-google-auth                       1.4.0
Pygments                                 2.7.4
PyJWT                                    1.7.1
PyNaCl                                   1.5.0
pyodbc                                   4.0.32
pyOpenSSL                                19.1.0
pyparsing                                2.4.7
pyrsistent                               0.17.3
pysftp                                   0.2.9
python-daemon                            2.3.0
python-dateutil                          2.8.1
python-editor                            1.0.4
python-http-client                       3.3.7
python-ldap                              3.4.0
python-nvd3                              0.15.0
python-slugify                           6.1.1
python3-openid                           3.2.0
pytz                                     2020.5
pytzdata                                 2020.1
PyYAML                                   5.4.1
redis                                    3.5.3
redshift-connector                       2.0.906
requests                                 2.27.1
requests-oauthlib                        1.3.1
rfc3986                                  1.5.0
rich                                     12.3.0
rsa                                      4.8
s3transfer                               0.3.4
scikit-learn                             0.24.1
scipy                                    1.7.3
scramp                                   1.4.1
sendgrid                                 6.9.7
setproctitle                             1.2.1
setuptools                               57.5.0
six                                      1.15.0
sklearn                                  0.0
slack-sdk                                3.15.2
slackclient                              1.0.7
sniffio                                  1.2.0
snowflake-connector-python               2.7.7
snowflake-sqlalchemy                     1.3.4
sortedcontainers                         2.4.0
soupsieve                                2.3.2.post1
SQLAlchemy                               1.4.9
sqlalchemy-bigquery                      1.4.3
SQLAlchemy-JSONField                     1.0.0
sqlalchemy-redshift                      0.8.9
SQLAlchemy-Utils                         0.38.2
sqlparse                                 0.4.1
sshtunnel                                0.4.0
starkbank-ecdsa                          2.0.3
statsd                                   3.3.0
swagger-ui-bundle                        0.0.8
tabulate                                 0.8.7
tblib                                    1.7.0
tenacity                                 8.0.1
termcolor                                1.1.0
text-unidecode                           1.3
threadpoolctl                            3.1.0
thrift                                   0.13.0
toolz                                    0.11.2
tornado                                  6.1
typing_extensions                        4.2.0
tzlocal                                  1.5.1
unicodecsv                               0.14.1
uritemplate                              3.0.1
urllib3                                  1.25.11
vine                                     5.0.0
virtualenv                               20.14.1
watchtower                               2.0.1
wcwidth                                  0.2.5
websocket-client                         0.59.0
Werkzeug                                 1.0.1
wheel                                    0.37.1
wrapt                                    1.14.0
WTForms                                  2.3.3
zict                                     2.1.0
zipp                                     3.4.0
zope.deprecation                         4.4.0
zope.event                               4.5.0
zope.interface                           5.4.0
```

Comment: Hi, please read [mre]. It's very important to show a **complete** example of how to reproduce the error.

Answer (score -1):

HI I think this provider is not installed can you follow some steps to confirm if this is installed

1. first open cmd and write docker ps
2. Then copy the cluster id of the webserver which will be like [image] in this picture cluster id will be like starting from 39d11(this will change your cluster id will be different )
3. after copying the cluster id can you go write this in cmd  type
   **docker exec -it cluster-id /bin/bash**
4. now when you are in the airflow cluster go to the airflow /dag folder and now type **pip list** and you can see there is no provider install and you have to install it here again thanks

Comment: I've added the output above, seems to be installed

Comment: Okay their might be the import issue i guess you copy from documentation, Can you use  this import in dag   " 

from airflow.contrib.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook  "

Comment: I believe that the api you are suggesting is for older versions of airflow, Im using 2.3.0, please correct me if Im wrong

Comment: the problem is your import is wrong that's why it was raising an issue if you see your import again carefully you are repeating snowflake after hook it doesn't work like that, and it doesn't relevant to the airflow version this is a provider or package. Can you use my import and test and let me know if there is an error occurs please paste the images as well